# Calling functions using a variable with self

Tags: python, tkinter

I have some code for an autocomplete combobox that I copied from the internet and I'm modifying it so I can change its properties like width, height, bindings, etc. through keywords like a normal combobox. I'm not sure how to go about calling the functions for the properties though because I need self. behind it to initiate the function. Here's a snippet of what I have:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.CBBox = AutoCompleteBox(self, height=3)
        self.CBBox.pack()

class AutoCompleteBox(ttk.Combobox):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        ttk.Combobox.__init__(self, parent)

        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            key(value)

    def height(self, height):
        self.config(height=height)

    def width(self, width):
        self.config(width=width)

my_app = App()
my_app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking about how to pass kwargs to the base class, just pass them when you call `__init__`:

```
class AutoCompleteBox(ttk.Combobox):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        ttk.Combobox.__init__(self, parent, **kwargs)
```

To call a method on the base class, use [super](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super). Or, do like you do in the `__init__` and invoke the class. `super` is preferred.

For example, if you wanted to call the `configure` method of the base class you could do something like this:

```
def width(self, width):
    super().config(width=width)
```

In this case it's not necessary, since `self.config(...)` will automatically call the `config` method on the base class since you haven't overridden that method in your class.

If you defined your own `config` method to do something else in addition to the default behavior, it might look something like this:

```
def config(self, **kwargs):
    print("config called:", kwargs)
    super().config(**kwargs)
```

Notice that if you remove the last line, when you call `config` it will print the message but it won't actually configure the widget.

Comment: Sorry, pressed enter prematurely on my last comment. The only problem I see with that is I don't always just want to do a simple .config. I might want to call a unique function depending on what's typed in as an argument. For example, I want to have a background text that dissapears when the combobox is typed into but that isn't a built in function of the regular combobox that I can invoke with .config. So I couldn't use the same function for height as I do for that.

Comment: @jh123: I don't understand what you wrote. If you want to call a custom function, you call it just like any other method: `self.x(...)` from within the class, or `instance.x(...)` from outside the class. This isn't anything unique to tkinter, it's fundamentally how classes work.

Comment: I'm not understanding completely I guess. If I wanted to call the AutoCompleteBox class and pass in width=6 to be passed immediately into the combobox config and another made up keyword argument called cake=7 to be processed by a custom function inside the AutoCompleteBox class, I'm not following how I would separate the two easily.